# Hangman output removes the wrong element

Tags: python

I've been trying to remaster my hangman game, but i ran into the problem

here's the problem

```
['p', 'l', 'a', 'n', 't', 's']
['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
Input ur guess : l
['*', 'l', '*', '*', '*', '*']
Input ur guess : t
['l', '*', '*', '*', 't', '*']
Input ur guess :
```

the first line of code is for easier viewing of my program

the problem is that the `.remove` command removes the right element the first time, but not the 2nd time

i think theres a problem with the for loop colliding with the `def()` creating different x's, hence the different values

here's the code

```
import random
words=["random","trees","plants"]

def gen_word():
    global censored_word
    picked_word=random.choice(words)
    word=list(picked_word)
    censored_word =["*"]*len(picked_word)
    print(word)
    print(censored_word)
    input_func(word)
    
def input_func(word):
    global censored_word
    user_word=input("Input ur guess : ")
    if len(user_word) > 1:
        print("Ur input length is too long")
        input_func()
        return
    for x in range(len(word)):
        if user_word == word[x]:
            censored_word.remove(censored_word[x])
            censored_word.insert(x,user_word)
            print(censored_word)
        else:
            continue
    
    input_func(word)
    return
    

gen_word()
```

Comment: Don't remove and insert. If you want to change the nth item of the list, just do `my_list[n] =  my_new_value`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question, but also problematic: 1) Try inputting more than one letter, it will raise an error when you call `input_func()`. 2) You're recursively calling `input_func` at every input. Eventually, you'll hit max recursion (granted, probably not in any of your tests, but since you're learning to program you might as well learn itright from the beginning ;) ). Consider reworking that in a loop instead.

Comment: @GPhilo What if i just remove the `word`  from the function and just `global word`, it would work right?

Comment: @Gphilo I also realised i forgot to add `word` inside `input_func`, that also solves the problem. Thanks so much!